# Как перенести проект с visual studio 2019 на visual studio code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

У меня есть проект в vs, но я хочу продолжить разработку в vscode. Как мне заставить vscode собирать и запускать проект. Если проблема заключается в том, чтобы настроить launch.json и tasks.json, то как правильно создать их, чтобы перенести проект.

Comment: Странное решение. VS Code - это как блокнот, но чуть более функциональный, а сама студия - полноценная IDE. Ну да ладно, проект у вас .NET Core или .NET Framework?

Comment: установите https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp при открытии папки с проектом оно предложет сгенерировать launch и tasks само, потом отредактируете, если нужно будет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У меня проект .NET Framework.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Да у меня сгенерировался launch, но он сгенерировался для .NET Framework. Я так полагаю, что его можно отредактировать так, чтобы сменить платформу?

Comment: VS Code поддерживает только .NET Core, видел способы запуска Framework, но там через [такие костыли](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707095/visual-studio-code-for-net-framework) и не всегда гарантирован результат, да и [не полная поддержка](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Desktop-.NET-Framework).